# Programming content that only appears for certain users

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin

I am a c# programmer new to SharePoint. The customer has a SP 2016 standard farm. I want to add a custom c# web-page to allow a user (who has the rights) to search using external API for an item.

I then want to programmatically add a web-page to SharePoint with which users (with lower rights) can view. Ideally the web-page should be located where the user wants (using some normal hierarchy in SharePoint).

This web-page would need to have custom code to call the external API and get an access token to allow it to play a video via a stream URL (with the token in the URL). I would use a third party javascript player.

What web technologies in SharePoint is appropriate for this version and purpose that I should be studying to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend You to create ASPX pages that with C# code behind.

General info about custom page development
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/walkthrough-creating-a-sharepoint-application-page

A step-by-step guide on how to create custom aspx page with C# code behind. Do not worry that is is for SP2013 - the principles stay the same
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/steps-to-custom-application-pages-in-sharepoint-2013-using-visual-studio/